# Replacing placeholders with SED

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scripting

I'm trying to replace [[****]] placeholders in a html file with values from property file.

Sample content in the input file:

```
<html>
<host>[[my_host]]</host>
<port>[[my_port]]</port>
</html>
```

Sample content in property file:

```
my_host=linkcmb.com
my_port=8080
```

My current script:

```
#/bin/sh

property_file=$1
input_html=$2
output_html=$3

IFS="="
while read k v || [[ -n "$k" ]]; do
  test -z "$k" && continue 
  declare $k=$v
done <"$property_file"

eval "$(sed 's/\[\[\([^]]\+\)\]\]/${\1}/g' $input_html) >$output_html";
```

Error: Html tags are getting evaluated too causing errors.

```
./some.sh: line 32: html: No such file or directory
./some.sh: line 33: host: No such file or directory
./some.sh: line 35: /host: No such file or directory   
....
....
```

Any advises will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: add sample input lines and expected output for clarity...  and sed is not appropriate tool to use on html files...

Comment: @Sundeep Updated the question, please check

Comment: imo, this is not suited for bash scripting and sed... I don't have experience with using proper html parsers... for given sample, `sed -f <(sed 's/^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/s|\\[\\[\1\\]\\]|\2|/' property.txt) ip.html` might work, but it will easily break for real use cases

Comment: `sh` is not `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your while loop with

```
. "$property_file"
```

However, I do not like the `eval`, and you do not need to declare these settings.
You want `sed` commands like

```
sed '/=/ s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/s#\\\[\\\[\1\\\]\\\]#\2#g/' "$property_file"
```

A lot of backslashes, the `[[]]` were a difficult choice.
You can use these commands using process substitution:

```
sed -f <(
   sed '/=/ s/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/s#\\\[\\\[\1\\\]\\\]#\2#g/' "$property_file"
        ) "${input_html}"
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score -1):

There is a regex option which is missing from sed, but it is present in perl. If you can use perl, anything between \Q and \E is escaped and taken literally.

The script needs to change to create a temporary perl file that contains all the substitution commands. It would be something like this:

```
#/bin/sh

property_file=$1
input_html=$2
output_html=$3

perlfile="$$.perl"

IFS="="
while read k v || [[ -n "$k" ]]; do
  test -z "$k" && continue
  echo "s/\Q[[${k}]]\E/${v}/g;" >> $perlfile
done <"$property_file"

perl -p  $perlfile $input_html  >$output_html

rm $perlfile
```

EDIT:
If one of your properties contains a slash (e.g., a path name), you may escape it directly in the properties file:

```
# input
<path>[[my_path]]</path>

# properties
mypath=dir\\/filename

# output
<path>dir/filename</path>
```

Same thing with backslash:

```
# input
<path>[[my_path]]</path>

# properties
mypath=dir\\\\filename

# output
<path>dir\filename</path>
```

Otherwise, you may need to add logic to the script to do so.